# Popup Not Displaying in ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I would like to add a my popup work. I am confused which is which, infoWindow, popupTemplate and infoWindow. I have tried putting popupTemplate together but it does not load. 
The basemap works alright but does not load the load the layer.

```
require([
"esri/map",
"esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
"esri/dijit/Popup",
"esri/dijit/PopupTemplate",
"esri/dijit/InfoTemplate",//new addition for infoTemplate
"dojo/domReady!"
 ],
 function(Map, FeatureLayer, Popup, PopupTemplate, InfoTemplate) {
//create map
var map = new Map("map", {
  basemap: "hybrid",
  center: [-0.345, 5.543],
  zoom: 19
});
//info template defination
var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${OBJECTID}", "${*}");
var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
  url: "http://192.168.1.2/ndigis/rest/services/map/GSMA/FeatureServer/3",
  outFields: ["*"],
  infoTemplate: infoTemplate
});

map.addLayer(featureLayer);


});
```

based on the implementation here https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=renderer_class_breaks.

Comment: why is url: set to **server1url/rest** when the comment has a local ip? Are you sure that isn't the problem?

Comment: when you copy/paste the url of the featureLayer into a new browser tab, is it accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module name for [Info Template](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/infotemplate-amd.html) is :

```
"esri/InfoTemplate"
```

So change

```
"esri/dijit/InfoTemplate" to "esri/InfoTemplate"
```